# Searching through a website with Xpath to find a text part

Tags: xml, xpath, import, google-sheets

I am trying to extract the word 'Nahrungsmittel' from the following page: [enter link description here](https://www.comdirect.de/inf/aktien/detail/uebersicht.html?ID_NOTATION=135287105&SEARCH_REDIRECT=true&REFERER=search.general&REDIRECT_TYPE=SYMBOL&SEARCH_VALUE=NLM)

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.comdirect.de/inf/aktien/detail/uebersicht.html?ID_NOTATION=135287105";"//td[@class='simple-table__cell']")
```

I am using the function: IMPORTXML from the google sheets. However, I tried varies ways, either its telling me 'content is empty' or I get the whole table. 
Could someone tell me, how I can get the the word? data classes are the same however there or two different attributes but I only want the word 'Nahrungsmittel' and not the word 'Branche' (see below).

```
<td class="simple-table__cell">Branche</td>
<td class="simple-table__cell">Nahrungsmittel</td>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.comdirect.de/inf/aktien/detail/uebersicht.html?ID_NOTATION=135287105&SEARCH_REDIRECT=true&REFERER=search.general&REDIRECT_TYPE=SYMBOL&SEARCH_VALUE=NLM",
 "//tr/td[@class='simple-table__cell']"), 64, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. This worked, did not think of it. However, just because I am  curious, how could I selected the word without the index function? Tried to find a way with the xpath language. For example other attributes I can search for like this: `=IMPORTXML("https://www.comdirect.de/inf/aktien/detail/uebersicht.html?ID_NOTATION=135287105";"//td[@class='simple-table__cell color--cd-positive']")`

Comment: in this case, all you can do is index it. in common scenario each piece would have own attribute/class/id which you could refer to

Comment: Thank you again. Since I want to write the formula as generic as possible this works not for all different stocks, since the index is different for others. Would it be possible to somehow use the Id-Word "Branche" which occurs on all sites and get the next ID, which would be in this case "Nahrungsmittel" somehow?

Comment: td class for Branche is same as a td class for Nahrungsmittel - so no

Comment: Thanks. Too bad. This makes the whole process much more complicated. As I understand the is no other way? So I stop looking.

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.comdirect.de/inf/aktien/detail/uebersicht.html?ID_NOTATION=135287105&SEARCH_REDIRECT=true&REFERER=search.general&REDIRECT_TYPE=SYMBOL&SEARCH_VALUE=NLM",
 "TABLE", 5), 3, 2)
```

[image]